# Center element horizontally in visible area in a scroll view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to center an element horizontally in the visible area of a scrollable grid. So the text in the last row here should be centered horizontally inside the blue line.

**This is what I want:**

[image]

When scrolling, it should stay centered and visible:

[image]

**This is what I've got so far:**

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6v0ybnd2/24/

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="otherContent"></div>
  <div class="grid" >
  <div class="row">
   Row - this is a long text in row 1
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   Row - this is a long text in row 2
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   Row - this is a long text in row 3
  </div>
  <div class="row-element" id="element">
   this row should always be centered in the visible area
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.otherContent {
  width: 200px;
  background: orange;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.row {
  height: 20px;
  width: 1400px;
  background: lightBlue;
}

.row-element {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100vw; /* This width should be set to the visible  */
  position: sticky;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  background: lightBlue;
}
```

```
const el = document.getElementById("element");
console.log(el.clientWidth);
el.style.maxWidth = el.clientWidth;
```

It works somewhat using `width: 100vw`, but only when the grid spans the full width. As far as I understand `clientWidth` gives the visible width of an element, however setting the `width` to that doesn't really work (presumably because it changes `clientWidth` again?

Any ideas how to solve this? Ideally only in css, but I'm assuming that's not possible. I'd also prefer not setting the position via javaScript, since that results in visible lag, so I think setting the width and using sticky is the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I came up with is calculate it manually. Here's the code (with React):

```
const rowRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

let scrollLeft: any = null;
let throttleScrollEventActive = false;



function handleScrollEvent(event: any, element: any) {
  if (throttleScrollEventActive) return;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    const left = element.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    if (scrollLeft != left) {
      scrollLeft = left;
      setVisibleButtonWidth();
    }
    throttleScrollEventActive = false;
  });
  throttleScrollEventActive = true;
}

useEffect(() => {
  setVisibleButtonWidth();
  const el = rowRef.current;
  if (!el) return;
  window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => handleScrollEvent(e, el), true);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', (e) => handleScrollEvent(e, el), true);
  };
}, [rowRef.current]);

function setVisibleButtonWidth() {
  const el = rowRef.current;
  if (!el) return;

  const parent = el.parentElement;
  if (!parent) return;
  const clientWidth = parent.clientWidth;
  const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  const left = rect.left;

  const vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0);
  let width = null;

  if (rect.left < 0 && rect.right < vw) {
    width = rect.right;
  } else if (rect.left < 0 && rect.right > vw) {
    width = vw;
  } else if (left + clientWidth > vw) {
    width = vw - left;
  }

  if (width != null) {
    el.style.maxWidth = `${width}px`;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `position: sticky;` to `position: fixed;`, doing it this way though you will need to move it more since it will cover other elements. I moved it below the other rows with `margin-top: 100px;`, but it depends on how far you want it from the other rows and `.otherContent`

Comment: Using `position: fixed` means it's floating above everything, I want it to stay inside the grid and inside the row. Additionally, this doesn't solve the problem of the text not being centred when the grid isn't covering the full width.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="otherContent"></div>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="row">Row - this is a long text in row 1</div>
        <div class="row">Row - this is a long text in row 2</div>
        <div class="row">Row - this is a long text in row 3</div>
        <div class="row-element" id="element">
            <span style="position: fixed"
                >this row should always be centered in the visible area</span
            >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check this out,

Comment: That's sadly not solving any of the problems I'm having and creating new ones. Same as eucalyptus' answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're after.
Wrap the text in its own html element (e.g `<span>`), make that element fixed, and center it horizontally like below.
The `translateX` repositions the element horizontally, and using % inside of it means percentage of the element's own width.

```html
<div class="row-element" id="element">
  <span class="fixed-centered">
     This row should always be centered in the visible area 
  </span>
</div>
```

```css
.fixed-centered {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Not quite. It's always visible and centred, but centred on the window and not inside the blue row. It's also not staying inside the row if the content around it is bigger.

Comment: Aha. I'll see if I can figure it out